# Complete Tech Spec

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, public-key, doublespend

Where can I find a comprehensive description of exactly how Bitcoin works. I'm not interested in an analogy, I want to know everything, including the maths.

Comment: maybe you can let us know, what you have done so far, then it might be easier to recommend. A first shot would be "bitcoin.org", and an online version of Andreas' book "Mastering Bitcoin".

Comment: I've read the White Paper, thanks to Adam and I've looked at the reference implementation, but seems to just be code, unless I don't know how to read it properly. I've now glanced at the book you mentioned and it looks like that could be what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Three resources:

1. The Bitcoin [white paper](https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-paper).
2. The [reference implementation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/).
3. The [Bitcoin improvement proposals](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips).